# Command find failed: not authorized on <dbname> to execute command { find:<collectionname>

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am attempting to execute FindOne from my C# MVC ASP.net application.

Unfortunately this fails with the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException'
>   occurred in MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll
>
> Additional information: Command find failed: not authorized on
>   twitterstream to execute command { find: "tweets", filter: {}, limit:
>   1, singleBatch: true }.

If I start a MongoDB shell and run the following commands:

```
> use twitterstream
switched to db twitterstream
> db.auth("demouser", "abcd")
1
> db.tweets.findOne()
```

The findOne() command executes and displays a record.

What am I doing wrong or what step(s) have I missed within my C# application?

To make the test case as small as possible I have reproduced this problem using a console app which is listed below:

I am using MongoDB 3.4.6.

The console app has dependencies on two NuGet packages; MongoDB.Driver (2.4.4) and mongocsharpdriver (2.4.4)

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
    </startup>
    <appSettings>    
      <add key="MongoDatabaseName" value="twitterstream" />
      <add key="MongoUsername" value="demouser" />
      <add key="MongoPassword" value="abcd" />
      <add key="MongoPort" value="27017" />
      <add key="MongoHost" value="localhost" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**MongoContext.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace DisplayingMongoConsoleApp
{
    public class MongoContext
    {
        MongoClient _client;
        MongoServer _server;

        public MongoDatabase _database;

        public MongoContext()
        {
            // reading creditials from web.config file
            var MongoDatabaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoDatabaseName"];
            var MongoUsername = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoUsername"];
            var MongoPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoPassword"];
            var MongoPort = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoPort"];
            var MongoHost = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoHost"];

            // creating creditials
            var credential = MongoCredential.CreateMongoCRCredential(MongoDatabaseName, MongoUsername, MongoPassword);

            // creating MongoClientSettings
            var settings = new MongoClientSettings
            {
                Credentials = new[] { credential },
                Server = new MongoServerAddress(MongoHost, Convert.ToInt32(MongoPort))
            };

            _client = new MongoClient(settings);
            _server = _client.GetServer();
            _database = _server.GetDatabase(MongoDatabaseName);

        }

    }
}
```

**TweetModel**

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

namespace DisplayingMongoConsoleApp
{
    public class TweetModel
    {
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("thetweet")]
        public string Tweet { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
namespace DisplayingMongoConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MongoContext mongo = new MongoContext();

            var tweetDetails = mongo._database.GetCollection<TweetModel>("tweets").FindOne();


        }
    }
}
```

**Update 1: Here are the roles demouser has:**

```
> db.getUser("demouser")
{
        "_id" : "twitterstream.demouser",
        "user" : "demouser",
        "db" : "twitterstream",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "twitterstream"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "read",
                        "db" : "twitterstream"
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: @Mate: Added the Mongo roles for the demouser under update 1

Comment: I updated my answer for MongoDB.Driver (2.4.4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got to bottom of this problem thanks to this link.

https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/553/authentication-mongodb-3.x-failed-with-mechanism-mongodb-cr

From this page the most important paragraph was:

> MongoDB’s default authentication method is a challenge and response
>   mechanism (SCRAM-SHA-1).  Previously, MongoDB used MongoDB Challenge
>   and Response (MONGODB-CR) as the default.

Reviewing the demouser before making any changes I would see the following:

[image]

The part to note is that the credentials used is SCRAM-SHA-1.

Following the instructions in the link, I disabled authentication and then using the following in the Mongo shell I changed my Mongo instance to use the old method of authenticating:

```
> use admin 
switched to db admin 
>  var schema = db.system.version.findOne({"_id" : "authSchema"}) 
> schema.currentVersion = 3 
3 
> db.system.version.save(schema) 
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

I then enabled authentication, dropped and recreated the demouser: note the credentials now use the expected MONGODB-CR.

[image]

A rerun of the console app as shown in my question and the findOne command now works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Mongo Driver:

```
<package id="MongoDB.Driver" version="2.4.4" targetFramework="net46" />
```

try

```
            var _conn = string.Format(@"mongodb://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}"
                                , MongoUsername
                                , MongoPassword
                                , MongoHost
                                , MongoPort
                                , MongoDatabaseName);

            var _client = new MongoClient(_conn);
            var _database = _client.GetDatabase(MongoDatabaseName);


            var twees = _database.GetCollection<Group>("tweets");
            var r = twees.AsQueryable().Select(x => x).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine(r.Count());
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer but what is this block of code doing? I can see you are attempting to connect to the database using a different method, an explanation of why I should use this method would be helpful. In addition why aren't you using the Find command as shown in my example?